# best kinect object detection in indigo

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, 3d-object-recognition, roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/12444/best-3d-object-recognition-package/) before, but since 2011 the world has advanced. I know for one that [roboearth](http://roboearth.org/) has simply stopped, splitting into two separate projects. Their latest release seems to be in fuerte.

I also know that [find_object_2d has a new 3d feature](https://code.google.com/p/find-object/#3D_position_of_the_objects_(July_2014)) which I aim to test out sometime soon. This DOES exist in indigo. Does anybody else know of any other packages that do 3d object tracking? possibly better than either of these? Does anybody already have experience with find_object_2d's 3D features?

(The reason I mention Indigo specifically is that I plan to use [rtabmap](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros) in conjunction with whatever object detection I do, and I would like to avoid needing to set up a new ubuntu, groovy, and rtabmap install)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207378/best-kinect-object-detection-in-indigo/) by [ThaHypnotoad](https://answers.ros.org/users/22185/thahypnotoad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2015-04-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a [demo](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#Robot_mapping_with_Find-Object) on [rtabmap](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros) integrating [find_object_2d](http://wiki.ros.org/find_object_2d#A3D_position_of_the_objects) (with 3D feature). You can take a look at the bottom of the referred [demo launch file](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/c139c263dbc32cc674eb5f385742eae403b6fb77/launch/demo/demo_find_object.launch). For live object detection using a Kinect, there is an example launch file [find_object_3d.launch](https://code.google.com/p/find-object/source/browse/trunk/ros-pkg/find_object_2d/launch/find_object_3d.launch) in the find_object_2d project too.

Cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2015-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ThaHypnotoad](https://answers.ros.org/users/22185/thahypnotoad/) on 2015-04-19**:
Thanks! Totally skipped over that. Really convenient stuff. Just about to try it out.